# How to get vertices for a sphere?

Tags: opengl, vertices

For a project I want to do, I have to be able to draw a sphere (using OpenGL). The thing is I don't know how to get the vertices for a sphere. The way I do circles is this: `for(int angle=0;angle<360;angle++){
Vertices.x[angle]=cos(angle)*radius;
Vertices.y[angle]=sin(angle)*radius;
}`
Is there any way that I can get the vertices for a sphere in a similar way?

Comment: why not just export a sphere from blender or mesa?

Comment: It's because I prefer to program things myself rather than use external programs such as blender to make them.

Comment: search about spherical coordinates, it's the same principle of doing circle